# Class based selectors for AppleScript list items failing for UI element objects

Tags: applescript

AppleScript’s *list* data type has only a very limited support for **boolean test specifiers**. Besides picking items by range (with the *item* keyword), specifying a class will work:

```
get every «class furl» of {1, "Test", (POSIX file "/posix/path")} --> {file ":hfs:path"}
```

When the list items are references, dereferencing with the *contents* keyword will work:

```
get every «class furl» of {1, "Test", a reference to (POSIX file "/posix/path")} --> {}
get every «class furl» of contents of {1, "Test", a reference to (POSIX file "/posix/path")} --> {file ":hfs:path"}
```

So why does the following code set `allTextAreas` to an empty list:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set allUIElements to entire contents of window 1 of someApplication 
    set allTextAreas to every text area of contents of allUIElements --> {}
end tell
```

given that `allUIElements` is a list of references to *UI element* objects, and that at least one of them is of class *text area*?

**Note I am *not* looking for suggestions how to retrieve all UI elements of a certain type from the list (a `repeat` loop will do that) – I would like to understand why the selector pattern fails in this specific case.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the UI elements from the application results in a list of *object specifiers*: application objects (a form of nested containers) where each item in the hierarchy has several properties, including a class – [Technical Note TN2106](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2106.html) might shed more light on this –, while your first example used a file URL (a type of file reference) which has a base class.

So you will need to use either an application filter reference form when getting the objects from the application or query the desired properties of the returned objects, for example:

```
set allButtons to {}
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Safari"
    set allUIElements to entire contents of window 1
    repeat with anElement in allUIElements
        try
            if class of anElement is button then set end of allButtons to contents of anElement
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
allButtons
```

Comment: Thanks, as noted in the edited question, I am aware of the option to loop through the list – that is dog slow on large lists, which is why I started looking for alternatives. Filter reference forms do not work on AppleScript lists (they must be supported by the targeted application’s object model), which leaves class selection. What I’d like to know is *why exactly* I can select on class in the first two examples, and not in the last – or, put differently, what the exact difference between the specifier `a ref to (POSIX File "blah")` and `button 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1` is…

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and I am aware of the limitation of the filter reference form - this would be used when getting the items from the application in the first place.  The difference is that your first examples used immutable items that have a class, while the later example uses an object specifier that has a class property.

Comment: Yeah, well, it’s‚ `entire contents` or nothing with System Events, no reference form accepted … but never mind, what I’m really trying to grok is the root issue: the `ref to (POSIX file "blah")` is an immutable item? I’d have thought such a reference is an object specifier too…

Comment: OK, here is another way to put it - your first example used a file URL (a type of file reference),  while the last one uses application objects (a form of nested containers).  Technical Note TN2106 might shed more light.

Comment: thanks for the pointer, although that TN rather suggests that the differences between lists and object specifiers should be smaller than they actually are, as far as my sleep deprived brain can fathom it … might have to reread it later. I’m taking away from all this the class selector pattern does not work on object specifiers at all, for reasons undisclosed (“this is not madness – this is APPLESCRIPT!”). Would you care to edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: ah, belay that part about “reasons undisclosed” – rereading TN2106, “The difference is that your first examples used immutable items that have a class, while the later example uses an object specifier that has a class property” has finally clicked. If you put that at the core of your answer, I‘ll be glad to accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it if I wanted to find all the buttons of the front window in Safari. Just apply this logic to your situation.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set allButtons to UI elements of window 1 whose class is button
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that was not what the question was about: I am trying to understand why this otherwise useful class selector pattern does not work on a list of references to UI element objects. Besides, your `every … of … whose` clause will only return the top level *UI element* objects of the window, while *entire contents* returns the whole UI element tree as a list.